# Run powershell script using php

Tags: php, powershell

I have a file which contains a powershell script that has to be run depending on values i submit to a php form.

I have already figured out how to run linewise commands.It would be great if I could pass the form values as an input to the shell script and get the output.

Any ideas as to how I could post the form values to the powershell **Read-host** element?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: If someone could please let me know a way to respond to Read-Host via php that would also be great :)

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have no clue as to how to input values to Read Host as of yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `Read-Host` in this case as it's only really useful for an interactive script where the user needs to be prompted to manually input values.

As you want to call the script from php, using parameters would be better. This way you can provide input to your script from the command line.

Updating this example script to use parameters...

```
$computerName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your Computer Name"
$filePath = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the File Path"

Write-Host "$computerName is your computer name!"
Write-Host "Your files are in $filePath location"
```

Which would generate the following output when run

```
PS C:\> Get-Something.ps1

Enter your Computer Name: SERVER1
Enter the File Path: C:\folder
SERVER1 is your computer name!
Your files are in C:\folder location
```

You would use parameters like this:

```
Param(
    [string]$computerName,
    [string]$filePath
)

Write-Host "$computerName is your computer name!"
Write-Host "Your files are in $filePath location"
```

Which would generate the following output when run

```
PS C:\> Get-Something.ps1 –computerName SERVER1 –filePath C:\folder

SERVER1 is your computer name!
Your files are in C:\folder location
```

Comment: Thanks loads. Is there also a method I could use to assign specific parts of the output to a php variable?

Comment: @Sandushi It would be best to ask a new question as it's a different subject to this one.

Comment: could you please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918185/how-do-i-assign-variables-from-powershell-script-to-php?